# Is it possible to find Lottie file by json url?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native, lottie

Network Lottie used in mobile app: https://assets8.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_hp09atmh.json

I tried to transfer this lottie file from network mode to memory mode and I could not find the lottie file through this url.
I would have downloaded it in .zip form if I could find it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your link in a browser
2. right click in browser
3. click - "save as.."
4. click save your file "lf20_hp09atmh.json"